# Yes /No : Is this function is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Is of the following statement is True ?

Does there  exists a strictly increasing  function from $\mathbb{Z}$  to $\mathbb{N}$ ?

My attempt : I thinks Yes take  $f : \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

$f(x) = \begin{cases}  1 \ \text{if x= 0} , \\ - x \ \text{if  x} <  1 \\ \ x  \ \text{if x } > 1 \end{cases}$

Is this function is  correct ?

Comment: $-2 <2$ but $f(-2)=f(2)$ so yuor example doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct, since $0<1$, but $f(0)=f(1)$.

The answer is negative. The set $f(\mathbb Z)$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers and therefore it has a smallest element $N$. Take $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $f(k)=N$. Then $k-1<k$, but $f(k-1)\geqslant N=f(k)$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no strictly increasing function from $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb N$. If there is such a map then $f(0)$ must be some positive integer $n$. Looking at $f(-1), f(-2),..$ we see that there are infinitely many positive integers less than $n$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't. A strictly increasing function must be injective, yet we have $f(-2) = f(2)$.

Furthermore, $f$ isn't defined for $x = \pm 1$.

There is no strictly increasing function $f : \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$.

**proof**
Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$.
Consider $a := \min \operatorname{Im}(f)$. There must be $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(z) = a$ since $a \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$.

$z - 1 < z$, yet we must have $f(z - 1) \geqslant a$, hence $f$ isn't strictly increasing.